# How to get multiple answers from same regex pattern in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a file name as `ART-123456-123_GIT.tif`

- `^[^-]+-([^_]+).*` - this regex gives output as `ART-123456`
- `^[^-]+-([^-]+).*` - this regex gives output as `123456`
- `^[^-]+-[^-]+-([^_]+).*` - this gives output as `123`
- `[^_]+.([^.]+).*` - this gives output as `GIT`

I want to write a single regex pattern to extract all these 4 outputs

I tried in the following way

```
(^[^-]+-([^_]+).*)(^[^-]+-([^-]+).*)(^[^-]+-[^-]+-([^_]+).*)([^_]+.([^.]+).*)
```

Then getting the output as group(0) group(1) but it shows error. How can I achieve this?

I would like to capture ART-123456 ,123456,123,GIT all four in different capture groups.

Comment: You need to be more precise about acceptable name format. For instance `[A-Z]+-\d{6}-\d{3}_[A-Z]{3}.[A-Z]{3}` should match current file name and you can add groups to capture specific parts of it if you want. But I am not sure if that is the format which will match all possible file names.

Comment: Please clarify what you would like to capture in capture groups.

Comment: I would like to capture ART-123456 ,123456,123,GIT all four in the capture group

Comment: In one capture group or in four different capture groups?

Comment: in four different capture groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following expression:

```
^([^-]+-([^-]+))-([^_]+)_([^.]+)
```

Captured groups:

```
Group 1.    0-10    `ART-123456`
Group 2.    4-10    `123456`
Group 3.    11-14   `123`
Group 4.    15-18   `GIT`
```

You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/8ittZs/1).